# No Headers in Apollo Client Context

Tags: next.js, apollo-client

I'm using a cookie based authentication in my app. In order to authenticate my requests, I came up with this piece of code:

```
import { HttpLink } from "@apollo/client";
import { setContext } from "@apollo/client/link/context";
import { ACCESS_TOKEN_COOKIE_NAME } from "constants/cookies";
import { getCookie } from "./cookies";

const apiBaseUrl = process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_API_BASE_URL;

// eslint-disable-next-line import/prefer-default-export
export const getApolloClientLink = () => {
  const httpLink = new HttpLink({
    uri: `${apiBaseUrl}/graphql`,
    // Pass credentials to the server
    credentials: "same-origin",
  });

  const authLink = setContext(async (_, { headers }) => {
    console.log("Current headers", headers);

    // Get the authentication token from apollo context if it exists
    const existingToken = headers?.authorization;

    if (existingToken) {
      console.log("WE HAVE A TOKEN", existingToken);
      return {
        headers: {
          ...headers,
          authorization: existingToken,
        },
      };
    }

    console.log("NO TOKEN");
    // If no token is found, get it from cookies
    const token = await getCookie(ACCESS_TOKEN_COOKIE_NAME);

    console.log("updated headers:", {
      headers: {
        ...headers,
        authorization: token ? `Bearer ${token.value}` : "",
      },
    });

    // return the headers to the context so httpLink can read them
    return {
      headers: {
        ...headers,
        authorization: token ? `Bearer ${token.value}` : "",
      },
    };
  });

  return authLink.concat(httpLink);
};
```

This provides me with the link that it passed to my apollo client:

```
export const { getClient } = registerApolloClient(
  () =>
    new NextSSRApolloClient({
      cache: new NextSSRInMemoryCache(),
      link: getApolloClientLink(),
    }),
);
```

Unfortunately, it always logs "NO TOKEN", and when logging the value of my headers, it always returns undefined. Did I miss something ?

Comment: If you're doing cookie-based auth, why would you need to send an `authorization` header at all? Just use the session cookie in the backend.

Answer (score 0):

Those headers are the headers of the request your Next server sends to your GraphQL server - they don't have anything to do with the headers of the request your Browser sent to your Next server. You'll have to use the Next.js `headers()` and `cookies()` functions for that.